# Python C-API: How to use the returned python dictionary in Objective-C?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, cpython

My Python script `app.py` has this function for example:

```
def testmethod(x):
    return {"steps":["hello","world"]}
```

I am using Python C-API in Objective-C as follows:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyObject *pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("app");
PyObject* pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);
        
PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,(char*)"testmethod");
PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyFloat_FromDouble(223.22));
PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args);
NSLog(@"Check for dict: %d",PyDict_Check(myResult)); // Prints true!!!!!!!!!!!! So definitely a dictionary
```

After this, I am not really sure how I can convert the `myResult` to retrieve my dictionary. For doubles and strings, we usually use the `PyFloat_AsDouble` and `PyUnicode_AsUTF8String`, `PyBytes_AsString` functions but I can't seem to find a `PyBLAHBLAH_AsDict` or equivalent method.

```
double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
NSLog(@"Result: %f",result);*/

PyObject* pStrObj = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(myResult);
char* zStr = PyBytes_AsString(pStrObj);
NSLog(@"String: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:zStr]);
```

I don't have much experience with Objective-C so maybe I am not looking at the right place.

How can I convert the `PyObject` to a NSDictionary?

I am basically looking for a C way of accessing the dictionary first (a map for example) which I can then use Objective-C methods to convert to NSDictionary. Similar to how I used PyUnicode_AsUTF8String, PyBytes_AsString and stringWithUTF8String all combined together to get a NSString out of the Python String. Looking for something similar for dictionaries.

I have figured out a way to achieve this but I don't know if this is the best possible way of doing this. I modified my python script to use `json.dumps` to return a string representation of the dictionary. Then in my Objective-C code, I first get the string, then use `JSONObjectWithData` to convert the json string to a NSDictionary. This works for now but I am curious if there is a better way of doing this without having to return string instead of dictionary from Python. This seems more like a workaround solution to me. Here's what I have now:

**app.py:**

```
import json
def testmethod(x):
    return json.dumps({"steps":["hello","world"]})
```

**Objective-C:**

```
Py_Initialize();
PyObject *pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("app");
PyObject* pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);
        
PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,(char*)"testmethod");
PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyFloat_FromDouble(223.22));
PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args);

PyObject* pStrObj = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(myResult);
char* zStr = PyBytes_AsString(pStrObj);
NSString *jsonStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:zStr];
NSLog(@"String: %@",jsonStr);

NSError *error;
NSData *data = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@",dictionary);
```

Comment: Objective-C is not C or C++. The Python C API is a C API, not an Objective-C API; it doesn't come with functions to convert Python objects into Objective-C data structures.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I understand that. I am basically looking for a C way of accessing the dictionary first (a map for example) which I can then use objective C methods to convert to NSDictionary. Similar to how I used `PyUnicode_AsUTF8String`, `PyBytes_AsString` and `stringWithUTF8String` all combined together to get a NSString out of the Python String. Looking for something similar for dictionaries.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you looked at PyObjC ? https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PyDict_Next`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_Next) to iterate over key / value pairs of the dictionary.

You should also provide the Python hash and equality functions if you are still going to be using `PyObject*`s. Otherwise, you should try and coerce them all into native types.

(This is in pseudo code since I don't really know Objective-C, but have used the C-Api and Python)

```
NSObject* convert_py_object(PyObject* obj) {
    if (PyDict_Check(obj)) return convert_py_dict(obj);
    if (PyLong_Check(obj)) return convert_py_int(obj);
    if (PyUnicode_Check(obj)) return convert_py_str(obj);
    if (PyBytes_Check(obj)) return convert_py_bytes(obj);
    if (PyList_Check(obj) || PyTuple_Check(obj) || PyIter_Check(obj)) return convert_py_list(obj);
    throw error;
}

NSDictionary* convert_py_dict(PyObject* dict) {
    if (!PyDict_Check(dict)) throw error;
    NSDictionary* native_dict;
    PyObject *key;
    PyObject *value;
    Py_ssize_t pos = 0;

    while (PyDict_Next(self->dict, &pos, &key, &value)) {
        native_dict[convert_py_object(key)] = convert_py_object(value);
    }
    return native_dict;
}
```

Another alternative would be to just use the Python API to access values of a dictionary. So iterate over all the values with `PyDict_Next`, `PyDict_GetItemString` to access string items with simple `char *`s, and `PyDict_GetItem` to access an arbitrary Python value.